# How to find out the embedded JDK version of Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to find out what JDK's version does my Android Studio use.
I'm confused, because i have many versions in my /Program Files/Java catalog

[image]

Unfortunately the project structure doesn't have any JDK's version number.
[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The embedded JDK is included in the Android Studio install. If you open the folder where you installed Android Studio, you'll see a jre folder in it:

[image: Image showing the JRE folder in the Android Studio installation folder]

Inside the folder there is a file called `THIRD_PARTY_README` in which the second sentence says:

```
%% This notice is provided with respect to ASM Bytecode Manipulation 
Framework v5.0.3, which may be included with JRE 8, and JDK 8, and 
OpenJDK 8.
```

I'm using Android Studio 3.0, in which the embedded JDK version is 8. To find the version in any later version though, go to `[SDK_INSTALL_ROOT]/jre/` and find `THIRD_PARTY_README`

---

`THIRD_PARTY_README` is in my system defined as a `file` and not a `txt` file. You can open it in Notepad, Notepad++ or any other text editor. The content is plain text. You can also look for a file called `release`, which contains similar information about versions.

Comment: Out of curiousity, does anybody know why this - which does indeed appear to be the jdk -  is in a folder named `jre`? My understanding is there a difference between the jre and jdk so I would have thought `jdk` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 5):

In the installation directory of Android Studio there is a "release" file where you will find the detailed java information.

Contents of C:\...\Android Studio\jre\release :

```
JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_242"
OS_NAME="Windows"
OS_VERSION="5.2"
OS_ARCH="amd64"
SOURCE=""
```