# RoomLibrary - Current JDK version 1.8.0_221-b11 has a bug (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8007720) that prevents Room from being incremental

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, android-room

I can't get the Room library to work.

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
```

It's throwing this error when I try to compile:

```
 Current JDK version 1.8.0_221-b11 has a bug (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8007720) that prevents Room from being incremental
```

I've updated the JDK to the latest version (8u291) but it still gives me the same error.

`Current JDK version 1.8.0_291-b10 has a bug (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8007720) that prevents Room from being incremental. Consider using JDK 11+ or the embedded JDK shipped with Android Studio 3.5+.`

I've checked my environment variables to make sure it's in the right path

[image]

[image]

I've tried configuring my `build.gradle` like recommended in the Docs

[image]

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_230_2

[image]

Doesn't work either.

Not sure what to do at this point to get the Room library to work

Comment: I believe  that you need JDK 11 or greater, that was the release that resolved the BUG in the JDK as per https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8007720 (the link referred to in the message).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this fixes the issue...but it works

In android studio go to `File --> Project Structure --> SDK Location` and change the JDK location to the
`Embedded JDK` one.

[image]

Comment: not works. Any alternate solution you have?