# how to use zulu-8.jdk work with kapt on android studio m1

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Current JDK version 1.8 has a bug that prevents Room from being incremental this look like
[Current JDK version 1.8 has a bug that prevents Room from being incremental](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822538/current-jdk-version-1-8-has-a-bug-that-prevents-room-from-being-incremental) , but....

m1 device optimize using zulu jdk

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home`

m1 device is not optimize when using sdk from Android Studio

`/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`

before i was use kapt `'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0'` where i have active to the plugin `id 'kotlin-kapt'`

> so how i can use zulu sdk instead of android jdk without `error bug that prevents Room from being incremental` ? any have trick ?

> my device is lagging, hot, and drained battery when use android jdk.

`Current JDK version 1.8.0_292-b10 has a bug` (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8007720) `that prevents Room from being incremental. Consider using JDK 11+ or the embedded JDK shipped with Android Studio 3.5+.` but what i have research the jdk 11+ is not support on android studio.

**edit 1**
I have try with Zulu-11.jdk
 `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` the exception is same

```
java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64. path=/org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64
```

Comment: I faced the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the problem. My steps for solving was

- Using Zulu SDK 11
- Adding dependency `kapt "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0"` on app gradle (If it isn't solved using zulu jdk 11)

If you are using Hilt add the following compile option for kapt at the end of app Gradle file

```
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        // These options are normally set automatically via the Hilt Gradle plugin, but we
        // set them manually to workaround a bug in the Kotlin 1.5.20
        option("-Adagger.fastInit=ENABLED")
        option("-Adagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation=true")
    }
}
```